# What's wrong with this null check?

Tags: java, list, null

```
List<Foo> results = null;
results = this.getResults();
if (results == null || results.size() == 0)
{
    LOGGER.warn("results empty");
}
else
{
    LOGGER.warn("results:" + results.toString());
}
```

The code above always produces the following output when `getResults` returns a null List.

```
results:[null]
```

I need to respond to this null scenario but don't know how to catch it.

Comment: in the getResults() method. Are your doing something like new ArrayList(fooArray) where fooArray's type is Foo[]?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your test so the issue must be coming form this.getresults() not returning what you want. maybe you should add the code of that function so we can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone is correct that your list contains one null value. However, I don't understand why it's necessary to check to see if the first element is null. It looks more like you need to rethink what's going on in `getResults()` and *not* put null in the list. I mean, there's no reason for us to assume there can't more more nulls, or nulls sitting in between actual objects.

Answer (score 5):

I think the results list has one item which is a null value.

I think the way is to check whether the list contains a null value at the the `0`th location, if not then the list contains at least one not null value.

```
List<Foo> results = null;
results = this.getResults();
if (results == null || results.size() == 0) {
    LOGGER.warn("results empty");
} else if (list.get(0) == null){
    LOGGER.warn("the list has only an null value");
} else {
    LOGGER.warn("results:" + results.toString());
}
```

Or

```
List<Foo> results = null;
results = this.getResults();
if (results == null || results.size() == 0 || list.get(0) == null) {
    LOGGER.warn("results empty");
} else {
    LOGGER.warn("results:" + results.toString());
}
```

Comment: Of course, the list could be full of good elements if all you check is the first element...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output, it looks like the List returned by `getResults()` has one null element.

```
List<Foo> results = null;
results = this.getResults();
if (results == null || results.size() == 0) // you could add the check here
{
    LOGGER.warn("results empty");
}
else if(results.size() == 1 && results.get(0) == null) // Or a new else if here
{
    LOGGER.warn("all I've got is a null in my list :(");
}
else
{
    LOGGER.warn("results:" + results.toString());
}
```